# jQuery.animate() fails in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-animate

Forgive me if this has been answered somewhere else--I've been researching like crazy, but none of the "fixes" I found worked for me.

Basically, I am using jQuery.animate() to move a div within an li tag down about 150px. It begins with a top: -150 and is hidden using overflow:hidden. Upon mouseover of the containing li, it should animate down to top:0. This all works marvelously in Chrome and FF, but in IE, I get nothing. I tried using the IE developers toolbar and traced through without any errors. It seems that for some reason the 'top' attribute just never gets changed in the animate function, but I am not understanding why or what I need to change to fix it. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

/edit le final

Finally ended up just working around the issue by using the "height" attribute of the div  for the animation instead of "top." That, along with the padding and border-width attributes and I was able to essentially get the same effect. Still not entirely sure why the "top" attribute wouldn't work, but c'est la vie.

Answer (score 1):

Hiya **working demo** tested in IE 8 :) http://jsfiddle.net/EbRgW/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/EbRgW/show/

Good read: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

`var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();` will do the trick in your case.

This will help,

**Jquery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() { //http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/
    var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    $jq('.accordion li').hover(function() {
        $jq(this).children('.accordion-textbox').stop().animate({
            top: '0px'
        }, 600);
    }, function() {
        $jq(this).children('.accordion-textbox').stop().animate({
            top: '-150px'
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

Comment: So I tried your fiddle and found it worked. However, in my dev implementation I had already used noConflict. Just in case, I tried using your script and found it still works in jsfiddle, but not on my site. Here's a link: [test site](http://www.thesurgeonisin.com/test/ce). I've continued trying to get this work, but just can't seem to crack IE. If you have any further insight, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Hiya @McCheesy I know you were missing $jq in your previous code try copy pasting the above code in you example this should work, let me know how it goes, Cheerios